# Why is the python module getting imported without its functions?

Tags: python

I have created a `setup.py` script for a gui application and a runner script `myapp`.
The runner script contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import myapp
myapp.gui_mode()
```

The application can be run from command line with `python3 myapp.py`
Here is how `myapp.py` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/evn python3

def gui_mode():
    run_app()

def main():
    print("Starting UI")
    gui_mode()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After I install the app with `sudo python3 setup.py install` and attemp to run it from console with `myapp`, I receive the following message:
`AttributeError: module 'myapp' has no attribute 'gui_mode'`

Ok, I start `python3` interpreter and check:

```
import myapp
print(dir(myapp))
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

I wonder, why is `myapp` getting imported without its own functions?

*UPDATE*

```
In [4]: print(myapp.__file__)
/home/tastyminerals/dev/NEFI2/nefi2/__init__.py
```

Here is the project structure:

```
APP2/
    setup.py
        myapp/myapp.py
        myapp/bin/run_myapp  <-- renamed runner file
        myapp/__init__.py
        myapp/data
```

Critical part of `setup.py`:

```
    packages=['myapp'],

    scripts=[
        'myapp/bin/run_myapp'
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import the `myapp.py` you've shown here, it will have `gui_mode` and `main` attributes.  I suspect that you're not loading the `myapp.py` module that you're trying to load.  Check the value of `myapp.__file__` to see which file you actually loaded.

Comment: It is loaded as  `__init__.py` which is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The runner script is named `myapp` and the module it depends on is also named `myapp`. Did you perchance name the package `myapp` as well? Something installed with `setup.py` has a base package name, so I'm guessing you probably named the package `myapp` too, so you'd actually need to import `myapp.myapp` (or rename `myapp.py` in the package to `__init__.py` so the package acts like a module of the same name).

It's a bad idea to overlap names like this in any event; if the runner script itself is named `myapp.py`, then it will import itself in preference to the installed `myapp` package; Python searches the local directory first, which is why it's a bad idea to name your scripts names that overlap Python built-in modules (e.g. never name a script `math.py` or you may screw up `import math` statements for other scripts in the same directory).

Comment: I've renamed the runner script, unfortunately to no effect.